# What is wrong with tyre

Tags: tires

Yesterday, I bought new tyre.  After driving for 15 minutes the air in the tyre is empty.  But the tyre has not pumped out any thing.

What is wrong with this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very clear case of either manufacturing defect or misinstallation. Take it back to the shop that installed the tyre and have them find out the cause of air leaking out. If the cause is manufacturing defect or misinstallation, as I suspect, demand them to fix the problem for free.

Of course, there is slight possibility that your valve (if it wasn't changed) is leaking. If the old valve is leaking, the cause was neither manufacturing defect in the new tyre nor misinstallation, so in this case you have to pay for the diagnosis and for the new valve and its installation.

Also, the wheel can be cracked. If this is the case, you have to replace the wheel.